# how to pass (like drag & drop) a file to an executable with a script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Pretty simple question I guess...

For this example, I have a directory with 3 files called L1.rph, L2.rph, and L3.rph and one executable called convert.exe

If I manually drag and drop each individual filename.rph file into the executable, it creates a filename.csv, however if I select more than one, it will only convert one.

I know there's got to be a way to do a for loop that will "emulate" me dragging and dropping all those .rph files in that directory to the executable and create all those .csv that I need.

Sorry...newbie with scripts, it probably would have been easier for me in Linux Shell but I have this exe in Windows...so I'm stuck.

I need this to run in Windows PowerShell

Comment: That worked!..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those exe files as arguments:

```
Get-ChildItem "Path" -Filter *.rph | ForEach {& "exefilepath" $_.FullName}
```

Drag n Drop is just same as passing arguments.